# Prove that order of cosets of a normalizer ($N$) of a subgroup $H$ w.r.t a subgroup $K$ divides $|K|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am stuck in solving an Exercise problem from Pinter’s Abstract Algebra book, and I need some help in finding an answer.

Here is the problem:

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $H$ and $K$ be any subgroup of $G$.

Let $N$ be the normalizer of $H$. (i.e., $N = \{a \in G : aha^{-1} \in H, \forall h \in H   \}$)

Let $K^{*} = \{ Na : a \in K \}$ (i.e.,the right cosets of $N$ w.r.t $K$)

and

$X_{K} = \{ aHa^{-1} : a \in K \}$ (i.e., conjugates of $H$ w.r.t $K$)

The author asks to first prove a one-to-one correspondence between $K^{*}$ and $X_{K}$ and then to conclude that the number of elements in $X_{K}$ is a divisor of $|K|$.

Proving one-to-one correspondence between the two sets is easy. However, I could not figure out how the conclusion follows.

Can you help?

P.S. The problem is given in the context of homomorphisms, Lagrange's theorem, cosets, and normal subgroups.

Comment: Do you know about group actions and the orbit-stabilizer theorem?

Comment: I added the "group-theory" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: @Bungo I am aware of orbit-centralizer theorem. But, I am not sure how it can be applied here.

Comment: $K$ acts on $K^*$ by right multiplication. This action is transitive (there is only one orbit, namely all of $K^*$). So by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, $|K^*|$ equals the index of the stabilizer in $K$ of any of the elements of $K^*$. For convenience, choose the element $N \in K^*$. The stabilizer of this element is precisely $N \cap K$ (it's not all of $N$ because only $K$ is acting). Thus $|K^*| = |K : N \cap K| = |K| / |N \cap K|$, which is certainly a divisor of $|K|$.

Comment: Thanks @Bungo. Finally I understood the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: so basically the exercise wants you to prove that the number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$ equals the index $|G:N|$ of its normalizer. Well, define a map from the left cosets of $N$ in $G$ to a conjugate of $H$ by $aN \mapsto aHa^{-1}$. You need to prove (1) this map is well defined, that is, does not depend on the coset representative (2) this map is bijective. If you confine yourself to $K$-conjugates of $H$, the proof is similar. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can prove that the number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$ equals the index $(G: N)$ of its normalizer. But, in the above-mentioned problem, we are NOT considering all the conjugates of $H$,  and we are  NOT considering all the cosets of $N$. That is why I am stuck. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SuhanShetty You want to examine the number of conjugates of $H$ **with respect to** $K$ (not $G$). Show that this equals the index $|K:N_K(H)|$ where $N_K(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $K$ (not in $G$). Specifically: $N_K(H) = \{k \in K : kHk^{-1} = H\}$.

Comment: Also, note that $N_K(H) = N \cap K$.

Comment: @Suhan Shetty: as pointed out above: $N_G(H) \cap K= N_K(H)$, hence $|K:N_K(H)|$ is the number of different $K$-conjugates of $H$. And this index divides $|K|$.

Comment: Thank you @NickyHekster.

Comment: I think $K^*$ is the confusing part.  Perhaps worth pointing out $|X_K| = |K^*| = (K: N_K(H))$; but there is no one-to-one correspondence between the set $K^*$ and the set of cosets of $N_K(H)$ with respect to $K$.